# Integrating MUPDF with android

Tags: android, mupdf, mingw-w64

I am using [this](http://howtojava.net/tutorials/android/integrate-mupdf-with-android-in-windows-7) link and the steps given here but I dont understand how to 
do  this step:

> Change into the android directory (from MinGW) (Note, the android directory, NOT the android/jni directory!), and execute: ndk-build. This should build the native code portion and output two libraries StaticLibrary : libmupdfthirdparty.a and SharedLibrary : mupdf.so in the libs folder. It will also be shown on the console.

can anyone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can understand from [this link](http://mupdf.blogspot.com.tr/)
it works in my project.

Comment: this link works but I am  again stuck in this step "That's all. Final step, create an Android application using mupdf android source (inside android folder). You can create this project as a library project and include it in your main project."  what does this means as I am a beginner I dont know how to make library project. And also I am working with Android studio.

Comment: completed integrating MUPDF library with my app. "http://ssahinkoc.blogspot.in/2014/10/integration-of-mupdf-project-as-library.html?m=1" this link helped a lot.